# C# reading binary how to do in python

Tags: python, c#, binary

I have the following code in c# and I need to do the same in Python, where I need to read a binary file and add a list of items to a list:

```
    private void Load(string fileName)
    {
        var buf = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
        Load(buf);
    }

    private void Load(byte[] buf)
    {
        if (_encoder.GetString(buf, 0, 3) != "XP2")
            throw new Exception("Bad file");
        var textCount = (buf[4] << 8) + buf[5];
        var size = (buf[6] << 8) + buf[7];

        var idx = 8;
        for (var i = 0; i < textCount; i++)
        {
            var byteCount = 0;
            while (buf[idx + byteCount] != 0)
                byteCount++;
            TextList.Add(_encoder.GetString(buf, idx, byteCount));
            idx += byteCount + 1;
        }
```

I have tried to convert it to python, but I think I don't understand binary files, and it does not work as it should:

```
my_string = []
f = open('C:\\temp\\2276.XP2', 'rb')

buf = bytearray(f.read())

textCount = (buf[4] << 8) + buf[5]
size = (buf[6] << 8) + buf[7]
idx = 8

i=0

for x in range(i, textCount):
    byteCount = 0
    while buf[idx + byteCount] !=0:
        byteCount += 1
        my_string.append(buf[idx])
        idx += byteCount + 1
    i +=1

print(my_string)
```

Any suggestion how I can do it in Python

Comment: *Doesn't work as it should:* how *does* it work, and how do you think it should, and with what input?

Comment: Could you upload the target file?

Comment: Sample file: https://file.io/qxlVVRGkvaC9

Output from the file should be: 9,10,8,76,28,7a,72a,105,51,49b,49,45,6,7,26,17,2,10a

Comment: `TextList.Add(_encoder.GetString(buf, idx, byteCount));` and `my_string.append(buf[idx])` also do not do the same. The C# version adds a string made up of a series of bytes. The python version appends one single byte.

Comment: The python version also fails to check the input file for the "XP2" Header string.

Comment: I know the header stuff are missing, how would TextList.Add(_encoder.GetString(buf, idx, byteCount)) be "translated" into Python, as I understand, in c# it look up the bytearray buf, item idx, and read number of bytes = "byteCount"

Comment: I did solve it... maybe it is a ugly solution, but it works:
`f = open('C:\\temp\\69487.XP2', 'rb')

buf = bytearray(f.read())

textCount = (buf[4] << 8) + buf[5]

size = (buf[6] << 8) + buf[7]

idx = 8

my_list = []
temp_char = ""

for x in buf[idx:size+idx]:
    if x != 0:
        temp_char = temp_char + str(chr(x))
    elif x == 0:
        my_list.append(temp_char)
        temp_char = ""
print(my_list)
print("Elements in the list: " + str(len(my_list)))`